# Purge local branchs in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Disclaimer: I am new to software development so my terminology may not be accurate.

The current source code looks something like this (this project use mercurial for version control):

```
---(r 1000) -> (r 1001) -> (r 1002) master, remote
      \
   (r 1003) -> (r 1004) -> (r 1005) feature1, local
```

I used a proprietary 3-rd party header in (r 1004) and replaced with it an opensource alternative in (r 1005). My understanding is that it still shows in the log, which is what I want to avoid. I would like to purge (r 1004) completely. How do I do that, using the above representation as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `hg strip` or `hg histedit`.  <s>In this particular case `hg strip -r 1004`.</s> **Correction**: use `hg histedit`, e.g., `hg histedit --outgoing` (see `hg help histedit` for more).  Both `strip` and `histedit` were once an external extension, but are now bundled (I'm not sure precisely which version(s) of Mercurial added them as standard).

Note that you must manually remove this particular revision from every repository that has it, otherwise it will keep coming back.  (This same issue occurs with Git, which I mention because the question is tagged [git](/questions/tagged/git) for some reason.)

Comment: Will `hg strip -r 1004` keep `r 1003 -> r 1005` in the local branch?

Comment: Yes, it's sort of like Git's `rebase -i` and deleting a `pick` line, in terms of overall effect (although the underlying implementation is quite different).  Note that hg also has `histedit` now, which is even more like `git rebase -i` (and more similar in implementation).

Comment: Erk, I just re-checked the Mercurial `strip` documentation and it says it removes the revision *and all its descendents*.  So my answer here was wrong.  You will need to use `hg histedit` instead!